# Trouble with showing a list of elements using column-count

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show 3 lists of items using column-count CSS3 property.
I want to show it using `Title column 1` as a `title` for my column, and show under it a list of elements.
My trouble is my columns are moving my elements in another wrong column.

This is my code:

```css
#columnasFooter{
  column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<ul id="columnasFooter">
    <li>Title column 1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Title column 2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
            <li>Item 9</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Title column 3
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: give a link to real code instead of picture

Answer (score 0):

This is totally normal behavior.

If you don't want to break your lists, you need to add additional style:

```
#columnasFooter li{break-inside: avoid-column;}
```

```css
#columnasFooter{column-count: 3;}
#columnasFooter li{break-inside: avoid-column;}
```

```html
<ul id="columnasFooter">
    <li>Title column 1
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Title column 2
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
            <li>Item 6</li>
            <li>Item 7</li>
            <li>Item 8</li>
            <li>Item 9</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Title column 3
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
            <li>Item 5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @eugneiodsjgfo If I answered your question, please accept the answer, so it wouldn't appear for others as unanswered. Thanx!